# Navigation Drawer list item not getting highlighted when clicked using appcompat for Android 2.3

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

When I click on an item in the navigation drawer, the item is not getting highlighted only when I run on Android 2.3.
But the same is working perfectly in other higher versions. I am using `AppCompat` library in the project.

I know, the `state_activated` is not supported in `API level` < 11, but what is the workaround available for this issue. I am not able to find a perfect fix for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Actionbar tabs are not supported in **GingerBread (android 2.3 and less)**. So you have to use **ActionBarSherlock** library to include navigation drawer in **API LEVEL < 11**

**[ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)**

Comment: I am using appcompat library to support the action bar in API LEVEL <11. Thats not the issue. I am not getting highlighted color on the selected items in the navigation drawer